# Unable to open numbers document stored on iPhone

Tags: iphone, ios

I am unable to open a numbers document I have used all the time.
Nothing happens, or I get a blank screen and have to close numbers.
If I try to copy or export the file it states The file does not exist.

The file is stored on the iPhone. I recently upgraded to iOS 11.1.2

I tried opening and copying the file in "Files" app, but the same there.
I tried General | Reset | Reset all settings, but it stil "does not exist"

Answer (score 1):

I found that if I connected the iPhone to my Mac, then iTunes could see the document on my iPhone.

I was then able to copy the file from iTunes and to iCloud Numbers folder.

On the Mac I opened and saved the document again (just to upgrade the file if that was the issue.)

Now I can open the document on the iPhone again.